# Ajax.ActionLink not working, Response.IsAjaxRequest() is always false

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have been googling/SO:ing this issue for a while and many seem to be sharing this, but I haven't found any successful solution to my problem.

Using MVC3 and Razor.

1. Master page contains:

   `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`

   `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`

   `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`
2. AjaxTest.cshtml contains:

   `<div id="AjaxTestDiv">content</div>`

   `@Ajax.ActionLink("Update", "AjaxTester", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "AjaxTestDiv" })`
3. AjaxTester action method:

   ```
   public string AjaxTester()
   {
       if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
       {
           return DateTime.Now.ToString();
       }
       else
       {
           return "FAIL";
       }
   }
   ```

I always get the "FAIL" returned, to a blank page, not in the targeted div.

Edit: Also note that if I remove the if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()), I still don't get back anything to the targeted div, but instead a  blank page.

Edit2: Looking at the HTML generated, this is my link:

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace"
data-ajax-update="#AjaxTestDiv" href="/Area/AjaxTester">Update</a>
```

Have tried switching the method to GET, to no avail.

Comment: Interesting, that extension always looks for the X-REQUESTED-WITH header to determine whether its an AJAX request or not, for some reason, that's not being supplied by the AJAX request...

Comment: I was thinking that maybe I have out-of-date MicrosoftAjax.js / MicrosoftAjax.Mvc.js, but I really can't find a download page for them..

Answer (score 47, accepted):

By default ASP.NET MVC 3 uses unobtrusive jquery with all the `Ajax.*` helpers. So start by getting rid off all MicrosoftAjax scripts (this useless c**p) and put the following instead:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and then simply activate unobtrusive AJAX in your web.config (if not already done):

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
</appSettings>
```

Now jquery is going to unobtrusively AJAXify all the links containing those HTML 5 `data-*` attributes.

Or even better IMHO:

In your view simply:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Update", "AjaxTester", new { id = "mylink" })
```

and in a separate javascript file AJAXify this anchor:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mylink').click(function() {
        $('#AjaxTestDiv').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Yay! Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for helping me unobrtrusivly de-cr**pify my code!

Comment: I wish I could vote you up twice, my friend.  I couldn't find any of the info you shared on asp.net/mvc (it seems to be rather outdated).

Comment: Worked great with a slight parameter change for me : `@Html.ActionLink("Test Two", "TestAjax", null, new { id = "mylink" } );`

Comment: Why do you feel it's better to write the jQuery by hand instead of using the Ajax helper methods?

Comment: @EricJ., probably because I don't like all the HTML5 data-* noise generated by the Ajax.* helpers in my markup and I want to to have total control over my scripts.

Comment: in asp,net mvc 5 why it works without adding these lines in web.config?

Answer (score 1):

Another IE-specific issue that can keep ActionLink from functioning correctly is covered here: [ASP.NET MVC - Prevent Cache on Ajax.ActionLinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031487/asp-net-mvc-prevent-cache-on-ajax-actionlinks)

Basically, IE sometimes caches Ajax GET requests, so setting the AjaxOption's HttpMethod to POST is a less fragile way to construct an ActionLink:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
       item.Name + " (Ajax link test)",
         "MyActionName",
         routeValues: new { id = item.Id },
         ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions()
         {
              UpdateTargetId = "divToUpdate",
              InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
              HttpMethod = "POST"
         })
```

Answer (score 0):

For those still facing this issue:

You should have below files in your project somewhere:

[image]

If not, below is the nuget package, either download this from nuget manager in your visual studio project or package manager console:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation/3.2.11/

Give reference of above added file after the jquery.min.js latest version in either your respective view or layout file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js** package in your project and it should work in the expected way.

Include the current script form
CDN: https://www.cdnpkg.com/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive

```
<script src="@Url.Content("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or install package
NuGet:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/3.2.6
and apply installed bundle.

Note that **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js** and **jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js** are not equal.

In my case this package was not installed and ajax.action link worked like html.actionLink and rendered entire view instead of inserting partial view in the target div.