# MVC3 AJAX ActionLink "Hello World" I can't get it to work

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, actionlink

I don’t know why but no Ajax is happening. It just links me to a new blank page and displays “NA”, because it calls the GetTime() function below:
Here is my Hello World code at Index.cshtml:

```
@ViewBag.Title = "Home Page"
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<p>Hello there! Click Update to see the current time!</p>
<div id="MyAjaxDiv"></div>
@Html.ActionLink("Update", "GetTime", new {id="MyAjaxLink"})
```

Here is the HomeController.cs code:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers {
    public class HomeController : Controller {
        public ActionResult Index() {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
            return View();
        }
        public string GetTime() {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
            return "NA";
        }
    }
}
```

I followed this link:
[Ajax.ActionLink not working, Response.IsAjaxRequest() is always false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973605/ajax-actionlink-not-working-response-isajaxrequest-is-always-false)

However, there is no difference -with- or -without- the AJAXifying code in a separated myscripts.js file as suggested by that post. It still links me to a blank page with “NA”.
This is the code declared in header of _layout.cshtml

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/myscripts.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

file “contents/myscripts.js”

```
$(function() { 
    $('#MyAjaxLink').click(function() { 
        $('#MyAjaxDiv').load(this.href); 
        return false; 
    }); 
});
```

Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the problem is your selectors.  Your Javascript is targeting id="mylink", but the link is named "MyAjaxLink".  Try changing the Javascript to this:

```
$(function() { 
    $('#MyAjaxLink').click(function() { 
        $('#MyAjaxDiv').load(this.href); 
        return false; 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: sorry. I have just updated it. It was copied from the other post. I actually used the correct ones in my code. Which were MyAjaxLink and MyAjaxDiv. Also, it seems to do the same thing to get me to the blank page, with or without the scripts.

Comment: Gotcha ... you also have "Html.ActionLink", did you write / mean to write "Ajax.ActionLink"?

Comment: D: OMG! Yes! hmm. 2nd question... now it works, but the time only updates first time, then it is no longer refreshing...(edit: I got it, add this to the front of GetTime() ...  [OutputCache(NoStore = true, VaryByParam = "", Duration = 0)]

Comment: btw, when it is done correctly. We don't need that "Ajaxify" code above.

Answer (score 0):

When you ajaxify code, make sure you have following 2 scripts too included in either of your view or masterview

```
  MicrosoftAjax.js
  MicrosoftMvcAjax.js
```