# Log out view in mvc ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have build a website using MVC4 razor, I am using two kind of action link for redirecting a view. "  @Ajax.ActionLink "   and "@Html.ActionLink ". I have a separate logout view, Issue is if i am on a views which is calling as @Ajax.Action link and session expired then my logout page is opened inside to the main layout view. I want to open a log out view in a separate view the same thing is happened whenever i use partial view.

Please let me know how can i fix this issue either using ajax.actionlink or partial view logout page will open on a separate view.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will need to do involves some server side and client side coding.

Firstly on the server side you will need to capture requests where the users session has expeired AND they are using ajax.

If you are using the standard Authentication attribute you can extend it like this:

```
 public class AjaxAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    { 
        private class Http401Result : ActionResult
        {
            public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
            { 
                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                context.HttpContext.Response.Write("Your session has expired. Please login again to continue.");
                context.HttpContext.Response.End();
            }
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.Result = new Http401Result();
            }
            else
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }

    }
```

Use that attribute instead of `Authorize` on your Controller or Action.

Now to the client side, when a request comes back from the server with a 401 response you want to capture it and do something, lets use a Ajax Setup for this:

Stick this someone it will always run:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });

    $(document).ajaxError(
        function (e, request) {
            if (request.status == 401) {
                alert("Your session has expired. Please login again to continue.");
                window.location = "/account/logon"; 
            } else {

            }
        }
    );
}
```

And youre done.

Comment: Hi, I don't need to do any changes on ajax action link?    My ajax action link some thing like this : @Ajax.ActionLink("Actiontext", "Actionname", "Controllername", new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "ajaxStart", OnComplete = "ajaxStop", UpdateTargetId = "form" } })

Comment: It should be fine, the ajaxError should catch the error request no matter how you call the server as long as it's via ajax.  Give it a try and see how you go.

Comment: I had implemented your code and did some more googling. But i am getting this error:  <hgroup class="title">
    <h1 class="error">Error.</h1>
    <h2 class="error">The controller for path &#39;/.../login.aspx&#39; was not found or does not implement IController.</h2>   </hgroup>   ....I had ignored the routes path in global.aspx  but still getting error..

Comment: make sure you change this line to be the path to your login screen (or other) `window.location = "/account/logon"; `

Comment: I solved this issue by mentioned authorization mode in web config. Now getting another issue, I always redirected to the log out view. I mean  on your given server code i always goes into the else section i am logged in or not it's hardly matter i always redirected to logged out view.

Comment: this is my action view link:  @Ajax.ActionLink("Get Secret", "Secret", new AjaxOptions {  UpdateTargetId = "form" })  Controller code  :   [AjaxAuthorize]
        public ActionResult Secret()
        {
            return View();
        }     I am clicking in this link after the login session made successfully after the login but i got redirected to the logout view as i clicked into the link.

Comment: If IsAjaxRequest is not working have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4973718/148998

Comment: Thanks, It's working now. I included the below script to the view and it's perfectly working. Thanks!!  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>